# Does there exist integers $m,n$ satisfying a certain equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, binomial-theorem

I was thinking about the following:

Does there exist real numbers $a,b, c, e, f$ and integers $m,n$ (where $m \geq -1$ and $n \geq -1$ with $m+n \geq 1$) such that
$(-a + bc)^m (\frac{1}{a} + ef)^n = 1$. Since this is a perturbation to $(-a)^m (\frac{1}{a})^n=1$, we have that $bc,ef$ are small non-zero quantities.

We also have the information that $|a|<1$ and that there exist no integers such that $(-1)^m a^{(m-n)}=1$. The quantities $b,c,e,f$ are small.

I am trying to think about how to approach this question? Maybe a binomial expansion and neglecting some small quantities help (but it seems like it can get complicated)?

$\textbf{EDIT}$

$m,n$ are distinct integers. 
The case $(-a + bc)^m (\frac{1}{a} + ef)^n = 1$ can be thought of as a small perturbation of the case $(-a)^m (\frac{1}{a})^n = 1$. We further have the information that the perturbed modulus argument that is $|-a + bc|<1$ and $|\frac{1}{a} + ef|>1$.

Comment: Is the equality meant to be exact or approximate?

Comment: I think the equality is exact. But it will also be interesting to consider the approximate case and then considering/ thinking about the neglected terms which may lead us to equality?

Comment: Taking $\log$ of both sides we have $\frac{n}{m}=-\frac{\log(bc-a)}{\log\left(\frac{1}{a}+ef\right)}$, does that help?

Comment: If the equality is exact, then I'm not sure how to make sense of "neglecting some small quantities" or what the point of the condition that $b,c,e,f$ are small is.

Comment: Actually there does not exist distinct integers $m,n$ such that $(-a)^m (\frac{1}{a})^n=1$. The main case is a small perturbation to latter case and hence considering $(-a+bc)^m(\frac{1}{a}+ef)^n = 1$. Then would there exist integers where that would be satisfied?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin  this may simplify much but with the above conditions we have that $\frac{m}{n}$ is positive. rational? then we may have a diophantine equation! Can that lead to something?

Answer (score 1):

$a = \frac 12$, $b=\frac 32$, $c=1$, $e =-1$, $f=1$, $m=n=1$ works. (Many more examples exist.)

Comment: Thanks! sorry but $m,n$ are distinct integers.

Comment: @BAYMAX No issue, both brackets become $1$, so $m, n$ can be any pair of integers here and it’ll still work.

Comment: This works! but $b,c,e,f$ are small quantities. But how small? maybe that is where I don't have any information..

Comment: @BAYMAX you can make everything as small as you like. Set $a$ to be extremely small. $m = n+2$ to be large even numbers, $e=f=0$. Then we can vary $b$ and $c$; if both are $0$, then the left hand side is large, but if both are slightly larger so that $bc=a$, the left hand side is zero. A solution hence exists by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking in that way now but can you also see my new edit?

Comment: @BAYMAX Take $b=c=\sqrt{a^{n/m}}$, $e=f=0$, $m=n+2$, $a$ very small. This satisfies all your required conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I will think a bit more but taking $e =f =0$ means no perturbation. But we need to have perturbation so $bc, ef$ are small non-zero quantities.